# Finding average of an imported file-line in script

Tags: awk

I imported a line from a specific file using awk into my script like this

```
awk 'NR==5' file1
```

so it would import the line that looks like this

```
B 15.8 16.1 15
```

I want to skip B and find the average of 15.8, 16.1, 15, which is 15.63.

I cannot figure out how to find the average of the line, skipping the letter when I read the file in... can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B` is the 1st field `$1` in your input line. Just start processing from the 2nd field:

```
awk 'NR==5{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i; print sum/(NF-1) }' file
```